# How to sort on multiple columns using JavaScript sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I have following array that needs to be sorted with respect to search text 'John'.

```
  {id: 1, firstName: 'User', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Smith'},
  {id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Andrew'},
  {id: 3, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Zch', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 4, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Mason', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 5, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},


];
```

**Expected Output:**

Array should be first sorted with nickName (with search text) then lastName(with search text). If nickName is not present then it should sorted with respect to firstName(with search text) with ASC sorting order. 
Note: It should consider search text word as **'John'**

This sort resembles like Search with Sort in your mobile's contact app

```
[
  // sort with nickName as higher relevance considering search text as John
  {id: 4, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Mason', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 3, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Zch', nickName: 'John'},
  // sort with lastName considering search text
  {id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Andrew'},
  {id: 1, firstName: 'User', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Smith'},
  // sort  with firstName as nickName is null
  {id: 5, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},



];
```

I tried localeMethod

```
function sortByLocale(user1, user2) {
   var sortByNickName = user1.nickName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(user2.nickName.toLowerCase());
   var sortByLastName = user1.lastName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(user2.lastName.toLowerCase());

   return sortByNickName || sortByLastName;
}
```

But the result is not considering search text while sorting.
One approach, I can see is creating three different arrays and sort them and combined those sorted array
Any helps would be appreciated.

**Edit: Not considering the non-matched object with search text value**

Comment: The compare function passed to `sort` expects a number to be returned, not a boolean.

Comment: @Olian04, localeCompare returns number so in this sence everything is right but actually i read it 3 times and didnt get how he wants to sort it =)

Comment: @DmitryReutov The sort like how it works in Contact. If you type John in search box, then it will show all John with First name and last name with be in ASC order. Then once sorting with first name is completed, then it will show all the records where John is in last name and first name will be in ASC order

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, yes, finally i got and posted solution, please check...but without filtering out non searching text you provided in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add first search by name

```
function checkSearch (value)  {
   return (value.nickName === 'John') * -3 ||
      (value.lastName === 'John') * -2 ||
      (value.firstName === 'John') * -1 ||
      0
}

function sortByLocale(user1, user2) {
   var sortBySearch = checkSearch(user1) - checkSearch(user2)

   var sortByNickName = (user1.nickName || '').toLowerCase().localeCompare((user2.nickName || '').toLowerCase());
   var sortByLastName = user1.lastName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(user2.lastName.toLowerCase());

   return sortBySearch || sortByNickName || sortByLastName;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for perfect and clean solution

Answer (score 1):

You could take two iterations for the wanted order

1. one for the wanted string
2. for the order of the rest

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, firstName: 'User', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Smith' },
  { id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Andrew' },
  { id: 3, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Zch', nickName: 'John' },
  { id: 4, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Mason', nickName: 'John' },
  { id: 5, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
],
    search = 'john',
    check = (s => (o, k) => (o[k] || '').toLowerCase() === search)(search),
    keys = ['nickName', 'lastName', 'firstName'];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    const
        fns = [
            k => d = check(b, k) - check(a, k),
            k => d = (a[k] || '').localeCompare(b[k] || '')
        ];
    let d = 0;
    fns.some(fn => keys.some(fn));
    return d;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Upvoting the solution. Thank you